# Java Inheritance issue with static and non-static context

Tags: java, inheritance

Please help me I am facing bit problem in Java code.
I am not able to understand how to fix the error.
Please help.

```
    public class A {

    private int a = 100;

    public void setA(int value) {
        a = value;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    private int a = 222;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main(): ");
        a = 123;
        System.out.println("a = "+super.a );
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> int a in class Main must be static

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: int a in class Main must be static

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should tell us the error :).

It looks like you are trying to access a variable in a non-static context from a static context (main method is static).

You should do something like below:

```
public class B extends A {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    b.setA(123)
    System.out.println("a = " + b.getA());
  }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to declare another 'a' variable in the child class. If you want to access 'a' directly, you can declare the field in class A as protected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just to be clear prior to going to the code, your 2 classes, given they are both public, must be in their own separate files.

Now let's go to your code. The error lies first in this statements inside your main method:

```
a = 123;
```

You are accessing B's instance variable a from a static context -this is one.

Second:

```
  System.out.println("a = "+super.a );
```

A's instance variable a is never inherited by B because it has a private access modifier.
If you want to access A's a, you could create an instance of A, and use that to call the getA() method which  returns the value of A's a

Cheers,